# As a J-1 visa holder, am I allowed to make additional income in the US?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, income

I am living in the US under a J-1 visa. I am thinking of building and launching an iOS application that might bring in some additional income from the App Store (potentially hundreds to thousands of dollars per month).

As a "non-resident" under a J-1 visa in the US, am I allowed to receive additional income besides the salary at my regular job (the one I was brought here under my J-1 visa)?

Comment: Keep in mind depending on your employer, and what you signed, they may own the App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prohibition is on working for someone else, not on making money. You would not be an employee or contractor of the app stores, you will also be able to release the app worldwide, and you will sign up to those services based on your current citizenship and banking relationships in your country.

As such, I'm going to go with "Yes", to your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think anything would change if I would want to route all the app income to my US account?

Comment: @Andrei No and you will be liable for tax compliance no matter how you receive any earnings.